# array definition error: why do I have this error?

Tags: arrays, c

(disclaimer: just ignore mat_constr function because it's not related to this question (it's mat_constructor of another question I've posted, because I'm trying to edit the mat_transpose function on my own)).

this is a very simple exercise, yet I can't figure out how to define an array (correctly).

I have a

```
struct matrix {
size_t rows; 
size_t cols; 
double* data 
};
```

in the main function, I have to define a variable of type "struct matrix", and then I have to define the array. As follows:

```
int main(void) {
struct matrix A; 
    mat_constr(&A, 4, 4); 
    A.data = { /* a number */, /* another number* /, /* etc. */ }; 
}
```

the problem is that the compiler highlighted the first "{". in the array definition, and it says: "expected an expression".
this is strange, because this is the definition style of the array, am I wrong?

Comment: Pointers are not arrays. In case you actually had an array, which you don't, you can only initialize arrays during declaration, not assign to them in run-time. The answer to your question is to study the basics of arrays and pointers in your C book - you can't program by taking a guess at the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `mat_constr` allocates memory as a single array of `double`, and makes the `data` member point to it, then you can *copy* to this array.

For example using [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) and [*compound literals*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal):

```
memcpy(A.data, (double[16]){ 1, 2, 3, ... }, 16 * sizeof(double));
```

<sub>[I made an assumption that `mat_constr` allocates a single array of `4 * 4` elements in my example above. Please don't let us make assumptions, create a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead.]</sub>

---

You can of course copy a value to each element of the array individually instead:

```
A.data[0] = 1;
A.data[1] = 2;
A.data[2] = 3;
...
```

And if you want to set all elements to a single value you can of course use a loop:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    A.data[i] = 5;
}
```

Or if you want to set all elements to zero then either allocate with [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc):

```
A->data = calloc(A->rows * A->cols, sizeof(double));
```

Or use [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset):

```
memset(A.data, 0, 16 * sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that C has no notion of *array litteral*. And the equal sign can be used for 2 very different operations, assignment and initialization.

The brace enclosed expression can be used to initialize an array, but cannot be used to initialize a pointer nor can it be assigned to a pointer:

```
double data[] = {1., 2., 3.};  // array initialization: valid
double *data = {1.,  2.,  3.}; // INVALID attempt to initialize a pointer
double *d2;
d2 = {1., 2., 3.};             // INVALID assignment to a pointer
```